# cakephp datetime formatter not parsing time part

Tags: php, datetime, cakephp

I have an input which gives this string to be converted to a datetime field (this is the default format for `<input type='datetime-local'>` elements):

```
'2020-04-19T18:00'
```

I have configured the parser with:

```
Type::build('datetime')->useLocaleParser()->setLocaleFormat('yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm');
```

however what I get in the datetime field is:

```
'datetime' => object(Cake\I18n\FrozenTime) {
```

```
    'time' => '2020-04-19 00:00:00.000000+00:00',
    'timezone' => 'UTC',
    'fixedNowTime' => false

}
```

Nothing changes if I use `'yyyy-MM-dd'` or `'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm'`: I always get a value `00:00:00` for the time portion.

Comment: Please always include which version of framework you're using.

Comment: What type does the column in the database have?

Comment: cake php version 4.0.5. I have a datetime in the database, but the value never hits the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's small problem in your pattern, you need to escape regular text, as all letters bewteen `aA` and `zZ` are reserved as pattern letters, ie the `T` needs to be in single quotes like this:

```
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm"
```

See also

- **https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/format_parse/datetime/#datetime-format-syntax**